# How to select a group (object3d) with domevent.js?

Tags: three.js, dom-events

I've a problem with object3d selection on my scene.

I use the three.js r61 and the domevent.js libraries.

I have added the THREE.Object3D Patch, but doesn't seems to works.

I have a list of objects that are mesh or object3d.

When i try to capture an object click, all works fine if object is a mesh but not if it is a group.

Each object is added with objects.push(object); // mesh or object3d

Here is the code :

```
    //  Objects selection
THREE.Object3D._threexDomEvent.camera(camera);
THREE.Object3D._threexDomEvent.domElement(renderer.domElement);
for ( object in objects )
{
    //  Bind depends on object type
    var bindControl = objects[object];
    console.log('bind ' + bindControl.name);
    bindControl.on('click', function(object3d) {
        console.log('ok');
        seletedObject = object3d.target; 
        console.log('selected : ' + object3d.target.name);
    });
    ...
}
```

So the domevent works fine for a mesh that is directly in the scene, but if i click on a mesh that is in a group, as the group only is in the objects list, the click event is not fired.

I don't know how to make my object3d to be clickable.

If someone has an idea, it will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, the edit mode seems not to work,  the Hi all, on the start disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

The code of domevents.js doesn't works with groups because of two reasons:

1. To detect intersection with or without the descendants you need to pass the second parameter as true on the intersectObjects function:

   ```
   var intersects = this._raycaster.intersectObjects( boundObjs, true);
   ```
2. The event is attached to the parent element (the object3d or THREE.Group object) and when intersection is detected it returns the descendant object with the nearest intersection. So the _bound function will ty to get context of child element instead of parent. You have to change the behaviour of _objectCtxGet function:

   ```
   THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._objectCtxGet        = function(object3d){
       if(typeof object3d._3xDomEvent == 'undefined' && typeof object3d.parent != 'undefined')
       {
           return object3d.parent._3xDomEvent;
       }

       return object3d._3xDomEvent;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

So i found a solution don't know if it is the better one but it works at least with a group of 2 mesh.

Here is the code i modified in the ThreeX.domevent.js (in THREEx.DomEvent.prototype._onEvent)

```
    var objectCtx   = this._objectCtxGet(object3d);
var objectParent = object3d.parent;
while ( typeof(objectCtx) == 'undefined' && objectParent )
{
    objectCtx = this._objectCtxGet(objectParent);
    objectParent = objectParent.parent;
}
```

This is beacause the object clicked is not the one that is in the objects list, so we must found the parent that is in the list, and it work with this code.

Be aware that i've only tested it for my case and tested it in only some case, so take it carrefully.

Bye